# Unable to start Hiveserver2

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

I was following the official document to install Hive for the first time.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted

But when I tried to run **hiverserver2**, it is stuck as the screenshot shows.
Hadoop is installed correctly.
[image]

Here is server info

[image]

Comment: It isn't stuck, it is running! Hiveserver2 runs in the foreground. To run it as a background process, use `nohup hiveserver2 &`.

Comment: Did you try connecting to it? Open a separate terminal?